# Quantum Approximate Optimization Algorithm for $p=1$

Tags: qaoa

I was running instances of $3$-regular graphs with small number of vertices on Qiskit, and for $p=1$ the algorithm was giving always the exact solution for the MaxCut problem, after optimizing the parameters. I was wondering though, how do we know if a specific graph can't be solved on $p=1$ ? Do we know the limits of QAOA for $p=1$ in order to decide with certainty that extra layers are required, given the graph?

Answer (score 2):

We don't in general.

There are instances where $p=2,3$ or $4$ might still be not enough. QAOA is an approximate algorithm as the name suggested, so you don't expect it to find the exact answer.

You should take a look at this paper: [**Quantum Approximate Optimization Algorithm: Performance, Mechanism, andImplementation on Near-Term Devices**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.01041.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

In general, we don't know. It is mostly trial and error, depending on the graph instance. There exist a few examples in the literature where it is pointed out that the probability of getting the optimum is very low such as [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.04769). One could try to characterize such situations with a few graph properties that can help decide whether or not QAOA at depth 1 is "enough" depending how you define it. For instance by using Machine Learning but this requires finding those graph characteristics but that is likely hard to find. As a Machine Learning methodology reference, there is [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.08271).